# Grouping php array with numerical index

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

I want to group php multidimensional array like this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [DATEDAILYRPT] => Mar  1 2016 12:00:00:000AM
                [TODAY] => 17043140.0000
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [DATEDAILYRPT] => Mar  1 2016 12:00:00:000AM
                [TODAY] => 3805785.0000
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [DATEDAILYRPT] => Mar  1 2016 12:00:00:000AM
                [TODAY] => 49587.0000
            )


    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [DATEDAILYRPT] => Mar  2 2016 12:00:00:000AM
                [TODAY] => 16484380.0000
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [DATEDAILYRPT] => Mar  2 2016 12:00:00:000AM
                [TODAY] => 27123966.0000
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [DATEDAILYRPT] => Mar  2 2016 12:00:00:000AM
                [TODAY] => 50413.0000
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [DATEDAILYRPT] => Mar  3 2016 12:00:00:000AM
                [TODAY] => 16410000.0000
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [DATEDAILYRPT] => Mar  3 2016 12:00:00:000AM
                [TODAY] => 29247107.0000
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [DATEDAILYRPT] => Mar  3 2016 12:00:00:000AM
                [TODAY] => -20661.0000
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [DATEDAILYRPT] => Mar  4 2016 12:00:00:000AM
                [TODAY] => 18459587.0000
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [DATEDAILYRPT] => Mar  4 2016 12:00:00:000AM
                [TODAY] => 30079338.0000
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [DATEDAILYRPT] => Mar  4 2016 12:00:00:000AM
                [TODAY] => 0.0000
            )

    )
)
```

I need to group all 0 sub index with 0, 1 sub index with 1, etc.
for example I want to group 0=>0 with 1=>0,  2=>0, and 3=>0. also 0=>1, 1=>1, 2=>1 and 3=> 1 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If your PHP version is >= 5.5, you can use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) for this.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
   $groups[] = array_column($your_array, $i);
}
```

If your PHP version is older and you don't have array_column, you can use a nested foreach loop like this:

```
foreach ($your_array as $day) {
    foreach ($day as $key => $value) {
        $groups[$key][] = $value;
    }
}
```